# Как сделать .exe из C для 32x битной системы Windows сидя на 64x битной Linux?

Tags: linux, c, windows, gcc, кросс-компиляция

Как сделать .exe из C для 32x битной системы Windows сидя на 64x битной Linux ?

При команде:

```
gcc -m32 app.c -o app.exe
```

Появлялась ошибка:

> In file included from app.c:1:0:
>   /usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
>   `#include` 
>            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   compilation terminated.

Comment: обычный `gcc -m32`  не создаст на Linux исполняемый файл для Windows. Попробуйте mingw32 для сборки и wine чтобы потестировать или просто виртуальную машину поставьте с Windows (бесплатны для тестирования). [How to compile for Windows on Linux with gcc/g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033997/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решила проблему **с ошибкой** установив `gcc-multilib` командой:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

**Но** чтобы создать .exe для Windows сидя на Linux нужно:

1. Установить кросс-компилятор, например, mingw64 из менеджера пакетов.
2. Затем уже выполнить компиляцию следующим образом: вместо простого вызова команды `gcc` нужно вызвать `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` для **32**-разрядной Windows или `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` для **64**-разрядной Windows.

К примеру:
`i686-w64-mingw32-gcc app.c -o app.exe` - для 32x

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc app.c -o app.exe` - для 64x

Comment: Чтобы не писать префикс каждый раз в *Makefile* обычно прописываются вызовы утилит через *$(CROSS_COMPILE)*.